# Force being equal at all points in ideal string

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

If a person pulls an ideal massless string, why do all points in the string experience the same force? How to prove this rigorously?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a part of the string as shown in the figure
[image]

Now, an ideal string means that the mass of string is zero.
Now writing force equation on string gives us,
\begin{equation}
T - T' = ma
\end{equation}
where $m$ = mass of string and $a$ = acceleration of string
Now since mass of string, $m$ = 0,
\begin{eqnarray}
T - T' &=& 0\\
\therefore T &=& T'
\end{eqnarray}
Thus tension is same in an ideal string at all points

Comment: Thank you for the reply,a question,what are $T$'s here? I mean i am applying a force $F$ here of my own,so what does tension have to do with this?

Comment: @madness Tension is also force, it doesnt depend what you call the force in this case. You can assume any force you want

Comment: Thanks again,could you kindly do me a favor by answering the last doubt i raised in the comment section of the answer above?I will be greatly indebted.

Comment: @madness Answer to that question is in my answer

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward, no?  Take the free body diagram of any possible slice of the string, and the forces must balance.

If you're talking about a real string with some finite thickness, it's likely that the force will not be totally uniform across the cross section. Depending on how it is made, it might carry more load at the edges or at the center. But the total across the section must be the same.

Comment: Thanks but why should the forces balance?Also if you "Force balance" theory is true,why isn't it true for strings with mass?What role does mass play here?

Comment: @madness, if the forces didn't balance then something would be accelerating. The mass of the string would be important of the string were handing vertically. In that case the lower part of the string is only carrying the load (whatever is hanging on the string) but the upper part of the string is casting the load plus the weight of the lower part of the string, so the tension won't be equal along the string.

Comment: @The Photon thanks for replying,actually i didn't get why the forces must be balanced,i mean i am pulling a string,so all the points of the string should come down with an acceleration,so i don't get why forces need to balanced since the points are moving,also why did you bring tension into this?I mean i am pulling the string using a force of my own.

Comment: The question needs more clarity. Can you draw a figure? I don't know if the string is suspended from the ceiling supporting a load, stretched between two horizontal supports, being pulled like a streamer ribbon on a stick...?